# How many sequences of $L$s and $R$s of length $n$ have no consecutive subsequences where $|\#L -\#R| > k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

This question popped up in discussion with a colleague, and I'm anxious to take a crack at it.

Given some sequence of $L$s and $R$s, how many such sequences of length $n$ have no consecutive subsequences such that difference between the amount of $L$s and $R$s is more than a given integer $k$? A consecutive subsequence of some sequence $a_{n}$ is a subsequence $a_{n_{k}}$ such that $\forall k, n_{k+1}-n_{k} =1$.

Example:

$n = 10,k = 2$.
$RRLRRLLRLR$.

This sequence does not satisfy the condition, because the consecutive subsequence $RRLRR$ has $4$ $R$s and $1$ $L$, resulting in a difference of $3$.

Considering the sequence $RLRRLLRLR$, however, when $n = 9$ and $k=2$, one sees that the sequence satisfies the condition as no consecutive subsequence has a difference of more than $2$.

My question is to solve this for general $n,k$. I've tried some work with recursive relations, but I keep running into roadblocks. I don't know of any other simpler methods to solve this, but that's why I'm asking here!

Comment: Should anyone be wondering [A027383](http://oeis.org/A027383) gives the number of valid strings for $k=2$. Might be able to mine the references here for some ideas - they have a closed form for the even terms here.

Comment: This isn't the same - this counts sequences such that ALL subsequences have this property - here we only care about consecutive subsequences.

Comment: Oh - that's interesting. I ran a python program to check, these sequences agree for at least n=8.

Comment: Can confirm, the sequence in that link is for consecutive substrings, though they don't explicitly define it as such. Otherwise every string with length $\geq 6$ would fail, just pick the substrings of all $0$'s or $1$'s, and the sequence would $0$ out. Any answer should agree with these sequences.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I've redone my math and checked with this sequence and it works out, so it seems I've discovered the correct answer to my question myself! I'll write up an answer and post it here in a bit. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could begin by counting left-right paths of length $n$ that start at $(x_0,0)$ for some $0 \le x_0 \le k$, end at $(x_n,n)$ for some $0 \le x_n \le k$, get from one to the other by steps of $(+1,+1)$ and $(-1,+1)$, and never cross the lines $x=0$ and $x=k$.

This is not the problem you *want* to solve, but it is related. All sequences with no subsequence on which $|\#L - \#R| > k$ can be expressed in this way by starting at *some* point $(x_0,0)$, interpreting $L$ as $(-1,+1)$ and $R$ as $(+1,+1)$. Moreover, if a sequence has $\max |\#L - \#R| = j$, where the max is taken over all subsequences, then there are $k-j+1$ starting points we can choose.

So if we have a formula for the number of these paths, we get the formula you want just by some inclusion-exclusion. Moreover, you're not going to be missing out on a nicer formula, this way, because for very large $n$ and fixed $k$, asymptotically almost all sequences with no subsequence on which $|\#L - \#R| > k$ do have a subsequence on which $|\#L - \#R| = k$, and can be expressed in only one way by these left-right paths.

Left-right paths starting at $(i,0)$ and ending at $(j,n)$ are given by the corresponding entry of $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0  & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^n$$ except more generally with $k+1$ rows instead of $5$. This matrix has eigenvalues $2\cos \frac{\pi j}{k+2}$ for $1 \le j \le k+1$ and correspondingly nice eigenvectors, so you'll be able to get a formula in terms of powers of these eigenvalues for any fixed $k$; I'm not sure if there's a nice expression for general $k$.

Comment: I have solved this problem with the inspiration your answer gave me, so I'm awarding the bounty to you! Thank you very much for your help.